# How to determine if a control is a Checkbox or a Radio Button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have an if statement that neds to check if the control passed is a checkbox or a radio button

```
            If TypeOf (Control) Is CheckBox Then

                If count = 1 Then
                    text += Me.GetCheckBoxValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & " + '~' + "
                Else
                    text += Me.GetCheckBoxValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & "'~' + "
                End If

            End If
            If TypeOf (Control) Is RadioButton Then

                If CType(Control, RadioButton).GroupName <> "" Then

                    If Not Me._GroupNameArrayList.Contains(CType(Control, RadioButton).GroupName) Then

                        Me._GroupNameArrayList.Add(CType(Control, RadioButton).GroupName)

                        If count = 1 Then
                            text += Me.GetRadioValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & " + '~' + "
                        Else
                            text += Me.GetRadioValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & "'~' + "
                        End If
                    End If
                Else

                    If count = 1 Then
                        text += Me.GetRadioValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & " + '~' + "
                    Else
                        text += Me.GetRadioValueJQuerySyntax(Control.ClientID) & "'~' + "
                    End If

                End If


            End If
```

This fails as the checkbox and redio button derive from the same class, so how would i check if the control is a checkbox or a radio button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close; `RadioButton` derives from `CheckBox`, so they're both *technically* `CheckBox`es. So, in this case, you can flip the statement around and use `Else If` to get the results you're looking for.

```
If TypeOf Control Is RadioButton Then
    ' The control is a RadioButton.
ElseIf TypeOf Control Is CheckBox Then
    ' The control is a CheckBox.
End If
```

Comment: No, your answer had the check for `CheckBox` as the first `If` statement, and the check for `RadioButton` as a second (separate) `If` statement. Mine has the order of the checks reversed (important) and uses an `ElseIf` statement instead of a second `If` statement (also important.)

Comment: It still did the check in the wrong order, which would still give incorrect results. `RadioButton` **must** be checked first, because it's the more specific derivation of the classes in question.

Answer (score 0):

What?  Unless this is something peculiar to asp.net ...

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, _
                          e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
            Debug.WriteLine("rb " & ctrl.Name)
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            Debug.WriteLine("cb " & ctrl.Name)
        End If

        'reverse check
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            Debug.WriteLine("cb " & ctrl.Name)
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
            Debug.WriteLine("rb " & ctrl.Name)
        End If

        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop

End Sub
```

It looks like the order does not matter, but I did not test with asp.net.

Comment: In Windows Forms, neither `CheckBox` nor `RadioButton` inherit from each other. In ASP.NET, `RadioButton` inherts from `CheckBox`. Your example would work in Windows Forms, but the second `If` statement would give erroneous results in ASP.NET.

Comment: Learn something new all the time.